# angular-cli won't build my angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have inherited an angular 2 application which I know nothing about. I am absolutely new to angular and node.js programming. I need help building the application so that I can deploy it onto a Windows Server 2016 machine with IISNode installed.

I was referred to this site here for instructions on how to build an angular 2 application:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

I installed angular-cli and then tried to build my application by running: ng build. It gave me this error:

[image]

It says "You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command."

Note that it also says the current package I am using is soon to be depricated. I am using node 6.10.3.

So my questions are:

1) Where can I get the latest angular-cli package (for purposes of building my angular 2 application)?

...and:

2) What folder do I have to be in so that I'm "inside an angular-cli project"? Is the fact that this is an angular 2 project mean it just isn't an angular-cli project? If so, why was I told to build it with angular-cli? Is there a different building tool for angular 2 projects? (Ok, that was more than 1 question).

Comment: you have to cd to the folder containing a file called .angular-cli, if it doesn't exist then it's not an angular-cli project.

Comment: oh boy, you most likely inherited a a soon-to-explode project-bomb :D, that warning message means that the CLI version is most likely pre rc-versions

Comment: @gib65 can you post your package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Cli is just a command line tool. You should upgrade to the latest node version and issue `npm install -g @angular/cli` and to run any angular project you have to `cd` to the project folder directory which has a `package.json` file in it and issue `ng build`. Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Sounds good, but its not going to be that easy; most likely OP will have to take care of a lot of breaking changes and package incompatibilities in the case that he just directly updates to latest

Comment: @angular-cli is a non-existent package. Please correct your answer.

Comment: @R.Richards Sorry That was a typo. Its `anuglar/cli` I edited it.